# Does $4^k = 4 \times 4^k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to separate $4^k$.. I have tried breaking it up as both as $4\times4^k$ or $2 \times 2^k$.. But both of these feel wrong. I have reviewed the exponent laws and know how to use them with number exponents, but I am getting tripped up when there is just a single variable exponent.

I am trying to break it down for a induction proof.

Thanks.

Comment: looking for this? $4^k = 4 \cdot 4^{k-1}$

Comment: Do you mean $4^k = 4 \cdot 4^{k-1}$?

Comment: Yeah! are there any other ways to break it up? and thanks!

Comment: @Travis it may help to think of $4$ as $4^1$, or $4^k$ as $2^{2k}$, when considering exponent laws.

Comment: Yes, $4^k=2^k\cdot 2^k$ works also.

Comment: Alright, thanks again guys! Erick, your example helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4^k=4*4*4*\dots *4 $ total of $k$ times, and we can leave one of them alone, we get
$$4^k=4^{k-1}*4$$
We also know that $2*2=2^2=4$, then $$4^k=(2^2)^k=2^{2k}$$
Lastly, it's always good to think the power in integer and try to visualize it by trying it.

One good example would be $a^0$:
$$a^0=a^{m-m}=a^m /a^m =1 $$